# How to send Dialogflow ansers to email

Tags: dialogflow-es, webhooks, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to send the user responses that I get from a chat with a Dialogflow chatbot sent to a specific email. This is because I want the chatbot to handle user orders, capture them and send them to sales.

I'm fairly new to Dialogflow so I'm not that savvy with the webhooks and fulfillments. Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two thing here.

1. Setting up your dialog flow web hook, so that you can get all the response and request in your web hook.

A web hook nothing but a server. You can check the [this](https://abhinavkumar985.medium.com/nodejs-webhook-for-dialogflow-fulfillment-a8e392b257b8) article and set this up.

2. Once your web hook is ready and you are getting response and request. You can use `nodemailer` module to send email.

mail.js

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
// create the configuration
const mailConfig = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtpout.secureserver.net",  
    secure: true,
    secureConnection: false, // TLS requires secureConnection to be false
    tls: {
        ciphers:'SSLv3'
    },
    requireTLS:true,
    port: 465,
    debug: true,
    auth: { 
        user: emailUser, 
        pass: process.env.ADMIN_PASSWORD
    } 
}); 
//export the function to send the mail
exports.sendMail= async (myParam ) => {
const emailUser = process.env.ADMIN_EMAIL;


// TODO implement
let mailDetails = { 
    from: emailUser, 
    to: myParam.to, 
    cc: myParam.cc, 
    subject: myParam.subject,
    html: myParam.message,
};
const data = await mailConfig.sendMail(mailDetails);

return data;
};
```

You can simply import `sendMail` function with your parameters and you can also change the its behavior like aysnc or synch.

You need to call this function from your web hook.

Comment: Thanks, Abhinav. Can I use the same procedure with the inline editor?

Comment: Inline editor gets more complicated when you add more modular way or organized files like that. It will work, but you need to do most of the thing in same file. But on later it will be hard to manage. So, I would suggest to go with own setup.